# how to retain Select2 results after select?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

For example, when using [select2 muti-value](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#multi), user entered '**new**', and it showed

- **New Mexcio**
- **New Hampshire**
- **New Jersey**
- **New York**

After selecting '**New Mexcio**', and the user would like to select again from the rest of the 3 remaining. In order to to do that, the user has to enter 'new' again.

Is there a way to retain the results instead of clear out the '**query**?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to persist a query from one search to the next. You might want to check out the `nextSearchTerm` property.

To display the current value in the next search,

```
function displayCurrentValue(selectedObject, currentSearchTerm) {
  return currentSearchTerm;
}

$("#e1").select2({
  nextSearchTerm: displayCurrentValue
});
```