# select2: How to persist search term?

Tags: jquery, search, plugins, jquery-select2

I would like for my select2 element to not clear out the searched term when I click away from the menu. I have searched a lot for this feature and it seems to have one day been possible, but it [no longer works](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/1604) in version 4.0? I have also tried implementing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23985561/1199793) but it didn't seem to work.

My code currently is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function displayCurrentValue(selectedObject, currentSearchTerm) {
        return currentSearchTerm;
    }
    $("#reference").select2({
        nextSearchTerm: displayCurrentValue
    });
    $("#reference").select2({
        width: "100%",
        language: "pt-BR",
        ajax: {
            //omitted
        }
    });
});
```

No matter what I try current behavior is:

1. Start typing a search
2. Click outside the dropdown
3. Click again to open the dropdown
4. **Previous search is gone**

Desired behavior is:

4. **Previous search is preserved.**

Comment: could you post the html too ?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that has worked for me:

To preserve last string query

```
$(document).on('select2:closing','.select2-hidden-accessible',function(){
    $(this).data('kmselect2LastSearch',$('.select2-search__field').val());
});
```

To get and select last item according by last string query

```
$(document).on('select2:open','.select2-hidden-accessible',function(){
    if (typeof $(this).data('kmselect2LastSearch')=='undefined') {
        return;
    }
    var prevValue = $(this).data('kmselect2LastSearch');
    if ( prevValue != '' ) {
        $('.select2-search__field').val(prevValue).trigger('keydown').trigger('input');
    }
});
```